# Error in gradle: Design Navigation Library include

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, navigation-drawer, androiddesignsupport

I have trying to use the Design Navigation Library from Android so I have to modify my gradle adding ...

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
```

I have added them and this is my actual gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "demo31.navigation"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
}
```

So, when I try to build my project I have the next error:

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not find com.android.support:design:22.2.0.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/design/22.2.0/design-22.2.0.pom
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/design/22.2.0/design-22.2.0.jar
>            file:/usr/lib/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/design/22.2.0/design-22.2.0.pom
>            file:/usr/lib/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/design/22.2.0/design-22.2.0.jar
>            file:/usr/lib/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/design/22.2.0/design-22.2.0.pom
>            file:/usr/lib/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/design/22.2.0/design-22.2.0.jar
>        Required by:
>            DNavigationView:app:unspecified
>   Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.pom
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.jar
>            file:/usr/lib/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.pom
>            file:/usr/lib/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.jar
>            file:/usr/lib/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.pom
>            file:/usr/lib/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.jar
>        Required by:
>            DNavigationView:app:unspecified

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you updated your sdk recently?

Comment: No, I'm working with the same version that other days. This is my first try to make something with the Design Support Library

Comment: Did you update your Android Support Library and Android Support Repository?

Comment: @JoséCarlos You should update that.

Comment: I'm updating right now!!! Thanks @EllieZou

When I finished I'll try to rebuild my project and tell you the result!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your Android Support Library and Android Support Repository.